# Cloud Function with Schedule

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to do a cloud function by adding a Schedule to change the status of a node inside firebase, which is {active: true} to {active: false}

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.createPrd = functions.firestore.document('products/{itemId}').onCreate((ev) => {   
    db.collection('products').doc(ev.id).get().then( doc => {
        var dia = doc.data().limitDay;
        var mes = doc.data().limitMonth;
        var hora = doc.data().limitHour;         
        exports.schedulerFun = functions.pubsub.schedule(dia+" "+mes+" "+hora).onRun((context) => {
            console.log('Se acabo la buena onda', doc.data().productName)
            db.collection('products').doc(ev.id).update({
                activo: false
            })
        })     
        return 0;
    }).catch(err => {console.log(err)});          

});
```

It is the code I had thought about where I passed parameters that I took from firebase to activate the schedule, but firebase returns this error to me when activating the function through onCreate.

- Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

Comment: Doug addressed your core issue below, but note that the error message you're getting here is because you haven't returned the promise at the top level (which you'll likely need to watch out for when you rewrite in the way Doug suggests).  You need to do `return db.collection(.....` instead of just `db.collection(....`.  Read more about [promises in cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) -- if you don't do this, its likely the execution environment will stop your function early.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do isn't possible.  You can't declare and export a function inside another function declaration.  If you want something to run on a schedule, you will have to declare and export it at the top level of the file.

What you can do instead is have your function run on a schedule, but query Firestore to see how it should operate on each invocation.

Comment: I don't think that's correct either.  Please consult the documentation to learn the supported ways of specifying the schedule.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions